# android studio sqlite exceptions

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting an error when I click on the search button on my dictionary page. please help me out.

My database helper class is :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by me on 4/2/2015.
 */
public class wordshelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int version = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE = "phords.db";
    private static final String TABLE= "words";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_WORD = "word";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    private static final String TABLE_CREAT = "create table words(id integer not null , " +
            "word text primary key not null , description text not null);";

    public wordshelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREAT);
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void insertContract(Contract c) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from words";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID , count);
        values.put(COLUMN_WORD, c.getWord());
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, c.getDescription());
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public Cursor getMeaning(String search_word,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        String[] projections = {COLUMN_WORD,COLUMN_DESCRIPTION};
        String selection = COLUMN_WORD + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {search_word};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE,projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

My dictionary class :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Me on 27-Aug-15.
 */
public class Dictionary extends Activity {
    EditText searches;
    TextView words,descriptions;
    private EditText resultText;
    SQLiteDatabase sql;
    wordshelper wordhelp = new wordshelper(this);
    String search_word;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dictionary);
        searches = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
        words = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvword);
        descriptions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdescription);
        resultText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
    }
    public void onSearch(View v)
    {
        search_word = searches.getText().toString();
        wordhelp = new wordshelper(getApplicationContext());
        sql = wordhelp.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = wordhelp.getMeaning(search_word,sql);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String WORD = getString(0);
            String DESCRIPTION = getString(1);
            words.setText(WORD);
            descriptions.setText(DESCRIPTION);
        }
    }
 public void onSpeech(View v)
 {
     if (v.getId()==R.id.imageButton)
     {
         EditText result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
         promptSpeechInput();
     }
 }
    public void promptSpeechInput(){
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "say something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Dictionary.this,"sorry! your device doesn't support speech",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int request_code,int result_code,Intent i )
    {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code,result_code,i);

        switch (request_code) {
            case 100:
                if (result_code == RESULT_OK && i !=null)
                {
                    ArrayList<String> result = i.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    resultText.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My dictionary xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:background="@drawable/marshmellows">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Word/phrase"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Meaning"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok"
        android:id="@+id/Bok"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etsearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="onSearch"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/r"
        android:onClick="onSpeech"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bsearch"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bsearch" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tvdescription"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView10"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My contract class :

```
package com.example.pro.phord;

/**
 * Created by Me on 13-Sep-15.
 */
public class Contract {
    String word,description;
    public void setWord(String word) {this.word=word;}
    public String getWord() {return this.word;}
    public void setDescription(String description){this.description=description;}
    public String getDescription(){return this.description;}
}
```

my logcat says :

```
09-19 07:53:46.549    2325-2325/com.example.pro.phord E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pro.phord, PID: 2325
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:360)
            at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:376)
            at com.example.pro.phord.Dictionary.onSearch(Dictionary.java:47)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: please tell us what is the error?

Comment: That's a lot of code to read, please post only the relevent section

Comment: @Tauqir  ..... sorry ... new to stack overflow and new to android ... just learning from scrap ... i got the answer ... thanks anyway :)

Comment: @e4c5 sorry ... new to everything ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather posting this much of code...Initially explain what is the error you are getting and post the logcat report. After few suggestion either post sample or section of code where you are getting error....Anyways after going through error and code you made a simple mistake inside if condition in the onSearch method of Dictionary class

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String WORD = getString(0);
            String DESCRIPTION = getString(1);
  //remaining code
 }
```

change it to

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String WORD = cursor.getString(0);
            String DESCRIPTION = cursor.getString(1);
  //remaining code
 }
```

due to direct usage of getString it was looking in the resource file

Another advice would be rather using the column index use the column name example would be

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
}
```

Comment: it worked .... thank u so much ..... @shadowDroid ..... if u can i need u to tell me one more thing ..... how do i create a database externally and deploy it into my project ? .... like if i create a table of about 10000 words and their meanings i should get the meanings from that database or table when i search..... or how do i statically insert a databse into sqlite

Comment: Firstly to create SQLITE DB externally you can use various tools and plugins.I use plugin in Firefox to manipulate data within sqlite db. To your second question you can use the sqlite.db file in your assets folder and from there you can access it in your applicaiton; search for its tutorial. Accessing db via assets is the solution I have see so far...but you can do google search you might other solution. Hope I have answered to your question. If that is not what you were looking for then use google.. for such questions use GOOGLE SEARCH best solution finder :)